# How do I add a dummy Column to a query as a constant

Tags: mysql, replace, constants, union

I'm trying to figure out how to add a dummy column to state what table each row is from in my union function. I'd like to make it a constant so I can just label whether they are an artist or composer. I'm currently trying to use the replace function but I feel like there's an easier way to go about this

```
SELECT REPLACE(artistID,1, 'Artist') AS 'Artist or Composer', ArtistName FROM tblartist 
UNION 
SELECT REPLACE(ComposerID,1, 'Composer'), ComposerName FROM tblcomposer
ORDER BY ArtistName;
```

Comment: unless you have a particular reason to use `UNION DISTINCT`, you should always explicitly say the more efficient `UNION ALL`, not just `UNION`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a string literal.

```
SELECT 'Artist' AS `Artist or Composer`,
       ArtistName
       FROM tblartist 
UNION 
SELECT 'Composer',
       ComposerName
       FROM tblcomposer
ORDER BY ArtistName;
```